# Groovy Spring Boot REST service is throwing PageNotFound errors for valid paths

Tags: spring, spring-boot, groovy, thymeleaf

I have created a [spring-boot-troubleshooting repo on GitHub](https://github.com/bitbythecron/spring-boot-troubleshooting) that reproduces this error exactly.

I am building a Spring Boot-based REST service that will *only* be exposing RESTful API endpoints, absolutely no UI/views/HTML pages whatsoever.

You can see in that repo's [`build.gradle`](https://github.com/bitbythecron/spring-boot-troubleshooting/blob/master/build.gradle#L41) that the only two Spring Boot dependencies I depend on are:

```
,'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty'
,'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
```

So nothing view-related (Thymeleaf, etc.).

When you run that app and open a browser to go to the `FizzbuzzResource` URL you'll get:

```
Problem accessing /error. Reason:

Not Found
```

And then on the console you'll see:

```
WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/v1/fizzbuzz/12345] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
```

I'm wondering *why* Spring is complaining HTML-basedPageNotFound errors when this should be a pure REST service, and of course, I'd love to know what the fix is to get this working and returning my Fizzbuzz resource properly!

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable web mvc and make ApiVersionRequestMappingHandlerMapping a bean in the container otherwise Spring won't use your `ApiVersionRequestMappingHandlerMapping#getMappingForMethod`.

See my commit https://github.com/yaoReadingCode/spring-boot-troubleshooting/commit/6260c394f4c28d155bbf016a758f3d37a5682a9c.